# Where to get prepared Characters for Scion?

Tags: scion

I got invited to a game of Scion, a system I never played before. I got some 500mb of PDFs so "I can prepare my character the next vew days". Since I can´t tell if I´m going to like it to an extend making it worth to dig myself through, I´d like to use a reasonable character someone else prepared. (not eliminating own preparations, but allowing some diagonal reading.)

**Where can I get prepared Character/Hero for Scion?** (All panteons mixed. If it matters, I usually play the sneaky sort of Character, Thiefs and alike.)

Answer (score 2):

The [Scion Quickstart rules](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/89226/Scion-Of-Shadows-Yet-To-Come) contains six pregenerated characters, starting on page 15.

[This page](http://mephitjames.wikidot.com/scion) says that Scion: Hero, Scion Companion, and Yazata: The Persian Gods also contain pregenerated characters. In addition, the [description for Scion: Demigod](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=50371) mentions pregenerated characters. So if you have any of these PDFs, I would look in one of them.